# Make Spring 4 Batch service repeatable on Scheduled execution

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-scheduled

I've been trying to solve this issue for few days and I couldn't make it. I'm quite new with Spring 4, so maybe someone with experience can tell me how to do it.

I was trying to learn how to code a Spring Batch with the latest version of the framework. I followed the Getting Started Tutorial:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/

Once the job was executing, I wanted to make it execute periodically. Therefore, I went for a scheduled task:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/

It looked easy to put both ideas together. In practise, it was not possible.
I read a little bit and I added some code to make the jobExecution unique every time. Still, the coded step, once finished, never executes again.

I investigated a little bit and I've read about RepeatTemplate, but I don't see it clear how to make it fit with my code. Here you have the 3 relevant methods for the execution:

```
@Scheduled(cron="0 0/2 * * * ?")
public void run() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Job Started at :" + new Date());

    JobParameters param = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("newsSyncJob",
            String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())).toJobParameters();

    NewsJobCompletionListener listener = new NewsJobCompletionListener();
    JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(newsSyncJob(listener), param);

    System.out.println("Job finished with status :" + execution.getStatus());
}


/**
 * Execution of the job
 * @param listener
 * @return
 */
@Bean
public Job newsSyncJob(NewsJobCompletionListener listener) {
    log.debug("newsSyncJob execution started");
    this.init();
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("newsSyncJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .listener(listener)
            .flow(step1())
            .end()
            .build();
}

@Bean
protected Step step1() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
            .<NewsSync, NewsSync> chunk(4)
            .reader(filesReader()).
            processor(newsProcessor()).
            writer(stateWriter()).
            build();
}
```

Any ideas how to make the step reexecute successfully?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: For starters your setup is flawed. You shouldn't be creating a new Job instance each time you want to execute it. Also what do you mean by it doesn't re-execute? I also doubt you need/want `flow` but you should have `start` instead.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum for you comment. I replaced the Job set up as you suggested - `start(...)` instead of `flow(...)` and I had to get rid of `end()`.
Still, the Job only executes once.

This means that the method run() executes every 2 minutes (as the cron expression says). All good here. The problem comes to the line...
`jobLauncher.run(newsSyncJob(listener), param)`
... because `newsSyncJob(...)` is not invoked again. Is that normal?

No breakpoint stops for `newsSyncJob()`, `step1()` or any of the itemReader, processor or writer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After M.Deinum's comment I made a little more investigation and I could solve it myself. Here is the explanation step by step:

The configuration was wrong because `newsSyncJob()` should be only executing **once**. It builds the Job and the bean keeps created as singleton. A singleton that can be executed as many times as you want.
Same happens with the step bean. `step1()` is only called once to create the singleton bean. As part of the Job, it may execute when the Job is executed... **as far as** it is configured properly. For now, the two methods look like this:

```
@Bean
public Job newsSyncJob() {
    log.debug("Building batch newsSyncJob...");
    this.init();
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("newsSyncJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .start(step1())
            .build();
}

@Bean
protected Step step1() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
            .<NewsSync, NewsSync> chunk(4)
            .reader(filesReader()).
            processor(newsProcessor()).
            writer(stateWriter()).
            build();
}
```

Now, **to make the step execute every time we run the job**, its scope needs to be changed. The step is composed by an *itemReader + itemProcessor + itemWriter*. By default, their scope is *Prototype*. This means that it keeps the state of the previous execution and it won't run again. To make it run again, the scope needs to be changed to *Step* scope. The code will look like this:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
ItemReader<NewsSync> filesReader() {
    return new NewsSyncReader(srcPath);
}

@Bean
@StepScope
ItemProcessor<NewsSync, NewsSync> newsProcessor() {
    return new NewsSyncProcessor(jdbcTemplate, newsRepository);
}

@Bean
@StepScope
ItemWriter<NewsSync> stateWriter() {
    return new NewsSyncWriter(jdbcTemplate);
}
```

Now to finish, the scheduled call will be configured in a different class using the dependency injection of the Beans created in the previous class. Something like this:

```
@EnableScheduling
@Service
public class BatchScheduled {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BatchScheduled.class);

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("newsSyncJob")
    private Job newsJobSync;

    /**
     * Scheduled run of the batch
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Scheduled(cron="0 0/2 * * * ?")
    public void run() throws Exception {
        log.info("newsJobSync started");
        System.out.println("Job Started at :" + new Date());

        JobParameters param = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("newsSyncJob",
                String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())).toJobParameters();

        JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(newsJobSync, param);

        log.info("newsJobSync finished with status " + execution.getExitStatus());
    }
}
```

We finally have a Spring Batch executing with a scheduled expression.

Comment: Thank you very much, It was missing me StepScope :)

Answer (score 0):

To add on the @Marc Loan answer, The itemReader + itemProcessor + itemWriter. By default, their scope were Singleton and not Prototype or StepScope which made their associated instances to reserve their last state.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31795630)